# Why my nginx keeps showing 403 for this very simple config?

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx and I am setting up a very simple server:

```
http {    
  server {
  listen         80;
  server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

  location / {
   root   /root/mydomain;
   index  index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

The config is that simple. But it keeps say 403 error. What should I do?

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: If I don't set any log stuff, where would it be? Would it even exists?

Comment: Yes, error log always exists in Nginx. You can find the default path of the error log by running the command `nginx -V` (that's capital V) and going through its output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because it does not have permissions to read `/root/mydomain`.

Typically nginx will run under `nginx` user. `/root` is typically only accessible for `root` user. It is generally a bad practice to put stuff into /root.

Comment: any suggestions to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @darkrose1977 learn about how permissions work in Linux, e.g. https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions.

Comment: @darkrose1977 e.g. one way to do this would be to move your `mydomain` from /root to something like `/srv/mydomain`. Then you can simply change ownership of the files to the `nginx` user: `chown -R nginx:nginx /srv/mydomain`.

Comment: It's weird that I have nginx installed but no nginx user. I also use cat etc/passwd, can't find the nginx user...

Comment: While I agree that keeping the site's files in /root/ (or its subdirectories) is bad practice, it is somewhat a bad practice to keep the files owned by the web server too. Let the site's files be owned by a normal user (without sudo) and let the web server have the permission to read it.

Comment: You can find the user of Nginx by running the command `ps aux | grep nginx`.

Comment: I tried many other ways and finally I use "chmod 755" to fix it. I don't know why at all.  I don't just have nginx user.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu I have got 3 lines, two of them are `root` and one is `www-data`

Comment: @darkrose1977 how did you install nginx? depending on installation method and OS you are using it may be running as something different. You really need to put some time into understanding how permission system works, otherwise you will continue stumbling in the dark.

Comment: Thanks, it's installed from my server provider. I will look up more information on my own.

Comment: Master process is always owned by `root` and then in your case, the child processes are owned by `www-data`. So, nginx runs as `www-data` in it.